# Python script runs in console but errors out as a script

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a script to pull some information from a site that I must login to use. I'm using Python 2.7.12 and Selenium 3.4.3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary='/usr/bin/firefox', executable_path="./geckodriver")

# Get to the login page
browser.get('https://example.com')
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Application').click()

# Login
browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('notmyusername')
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('notmypassword')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn').click()

# Open the application
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Banner1_ModuleList_ctl01_lnkModule').click()
```

If I copy this code and paste it into the python console, it runs just fine and goes to the page I want. However, when I run the script from the terminal (bash on Linux Mint 18), it errors out. Here's the output with the try and catch statements removed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Banner1_ModuleList_ctl01_lnkModule').click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 791, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="ctl00_Banner1_ModuleList_ctl01_lnkModule"]
```

I don't even know how to go about troubleshooting this. Any help?

Comment: did you tried with some wait?

Comment: @muraliselenium Do you mean putting a wait in the script? Selenium appears to wait until the page is loaded before taking any action. The script errors out and stops running after it can't find the element by id.

Comment: yes u r right. but some times thread.sleep will helps in java. so just to know are you tried or not.

Comment: @muraliselenium You're totally correct! That fixed it. Thanks, and have an awesome day!

Comment: good. have a nice day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per selenium docs, setting `browser.implicity_wait(10) # seconds` tells the browser to poll the page for 10 seconds before deciding the element isn't there. By default it is set to 0 seconds. Once it is set, the setting persists for the life of the webdriver object.

There are a lot of other nifty tools to wait for elements to load, documented at [readthedocs.io](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Answer (score 2):

What is most probably happening is that when you run the script from bash, the script runs too quickly and the `get_by_id` operation is started before the browser has finished loading the page, which results in this error.

As @murali-selenium suggested, you should probably add some wait time before starting to look for stuff in the document.

That can be achived this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from selenium import webdriver
import time

wait_time_sec = 1

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary='/usr/bin/firefox', executable_path="./geckodriver")

# Get to the login page
browser.get('https://example.com')
time.sleep(wait_time_sec)
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Application').click()
time.sleep(wait_time_sec)

# Login
browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('notmyusername')
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('notmypassword')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn').click()
time.sleep(wait_time_sec)

# Open the application
try:
    browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Banner1_ModuleList_ctl01_lnkModule').click()
except:
    print('failed')

#browser.stop()
```

Comment: Per the selenium docs, this might be an even better solution, depending on the situation `browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds`. This makes it continue to check for up to 10 seconds before erroring out. I haven't tested it yet, though. [Link to the documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: Can confirm, `browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds` is definitely the better way to do this, in general.